# Error in pyimport running python3 program

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Im running VS Code in Ubuntu 20. From what I have read it will only work with python3. When I installed lint,python3pip, and pytest it appears to have installed python 2.7 for these dependencies. The error I get says it has to do with syntax, but I believe it is actually because of the python2.7, as I am following a video and the exact same code works on his machine. I can't seem to find a way to just update pyimport to python3.
Here is a copy of the error message:

```
r/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/python.pu:507: in _importtestmodule
mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuressyspath=importmode)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
_import_(modname)
File "/test.py", line 21
out = getoutput(f'python3 {prg}')

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have to select the correct interpreter in VSCode which should be Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: I am using python 3.8 interpreter, but I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

To solve you need first:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then

```
pip install -U pytest
```